# Is it possible for a "range" function to return a value

Tags: vim

The following simple function is supposed to count and return the number of lines that are visually selected:

```
fu! TQ84_fu_test() range 

    return line("'> ")  - line("'<") + 1

endfu
```

If I try to call it like so

```
:'<,'>echo TQ84_fu_test()
```

Vim gives me the error `E481 No range allowed` (which is somehow documented)

Is there still a way to circumvent this behaviour, so that I can "fetch" the return value of a function operating on a range.

I assume I could set a global variable within the function and read this global variable after the function had been called, but, if possible, I'd rather not do that.

Comment: You should tell us a bit more on the context. Are yo doing a script? mapping? command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You needn't `'<,'>` in the command line, because the `:echo` command does not operate on ranges. This will not prevent your function to use the `<` and `>` marks which still can be resolved.

So, just after hitting `:` use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd> to delete the marks and use `:echo TQ84_fu_test()`. This should work.

Answer (score 1):

`range` only works with `:call`, not `:echo`. Since you don't use the `a:firstline` / `a:lastline` special variables that come with `range`, you don't need to bother here (using visual mode and its marks), anyway.